# Magento 2 CE - can't enable backorders

Tags: magento2, backorder

Can't seem to enable back orders.

**User Flow;**

Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Backorders > Set to: "Allow Qty Below 0"

**Error;**

```
"Something went wrong while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'qty' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status` (`product_id`, `website_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `stock_status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

**Trouble Shooting;**

- re-indexed all indexes
- cleared all caches
- Toggled all other values to non-default values under "Product Stock Options"

Answer (score 0):

Just got this error also...

A quick workaround is the following: Check if any of your products have empty/null value in the frontend (even virtual products) and add a value.

After that you will be able to change that option.